# QGIS causing recurrent crashes on multiple computers

Tags: qgis, windows, digitizing

I currently have lots of issues with multiple computers that crashes more than twice a day when the operators are digitizing vector layers. The computers are strong and run Civil 3D without any issues.
4 computers were bought at the same time with the same specifics (Be !Quiet Silent Base 600) but only 3 of them are experiencing the crash issue. None of the other computers we have at my office have the issue.

The crash I am mentioning is a basic shutdown of the computer, without any explaining message on a blue screen. The computers simply shut down as if the power was cut off.

I tried multiple versions of QGIS (3.16.4 was the original version that observed the problem and I tried other LTR from 3.16 and 3.18) but the results are the same. I don't want to use the latest version of QGIS as many routines we have built do not work on the most recent QGIS version as SAGA tools are being removed.

I'm not sure about any other relevant information I could provide to help the diagnosis, please let me know what can be added.

Comment: If it happens only with your new computers then it feels like a hardware issue. QGIS may be indirectly involved for example by generating CPU load that leads into overheating.

Comment: "Be Quiet Silent Base" is the brand name of a computer component (outside case) for home-brew high end gaming systems (https://www.bequiet.com/en/case/642). My Occam's Razor hypothesis is that there is a cooling issue. You should go back to whoever assembled the home-brew systems for you an have them run a hardware "torture test". In the meanwhile, it may be worth going into Settings > Options and throttling Rendering / Maximum cores and twiddling Acceleration / Enable OpenCL to see if those changes happen to bypass the issue in the short term.